# can seaborn normalise data such that y-axis is clear

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, seaborn

I plot time series of data where the y values of the data are orders of magnitude different.

I am using `seaborn.lmplot` and was expecting to find a `normalise` keyword, but have been unable to.

I tried to use a log scale, but this failed (see diagram).

This is my best attempt so far:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

gbp_stats = pd.read_csv('price_data.csv')

sns.lmplot(data=gbp_stats, x='numeric_time', y='last trade price', col='symbol')
plt.yscale('log')

plt.show()
```

Which gave me this:

[image]

As you can see, the result **needs to scale or normalize the y-axis for each plot**. I could do a normalization in pandas, but wanted to avoid such if possible.

So my question is this: Does `seaborn` have a normailze feature such that the y-axis can be compared better than what i have achieved?

Comment: The log should take care of it. What do you get if you don't use log?

Comment: it looks even worse without the log scale. The image is the result with a log scale.

Comment: Maybe you want `sharey=False`?

Comment: Can you share a sample of the data? It's impossible to know what 'price_data.csv' represents. Also, see this.

https://www.askpython.com/python/examples/normalize-data-in-python

And, this.

https://www.askpython.com/python/examples/standardize-data-in-python

Comment: @mwaskom,  excellent. This works perfectly. Would you like to post the same as a separate answer as this resolved the question and might also be useful for other users.

Comment: @ASH,  it was just generic data that ranges across the y-axis.  You are correct, I could (or should) construct example data. However, it appears as though mwaskom has provided a desired working solution with `sharey=False`.

Answer (score 0):

I post this answer which was **directly derived from mwaskom comment** `sharey=False`, with a small tweak as this format was depreciated in `seaborn` and `sharey=False` now goes into a `dict`.

The implementation is to add the keyword which takes a dict like this: `facet_kws={'sharey':False}`

So the answer becomes this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

gbp_stats = pd.read_csv('price_data.csv')

sns.lmplot(data=gbp_stats, x='numeric_time', y='last trade price', 
    col='symbol', hue='symbol', facet_kws={'sharey':False})

plt.yscale('log') # this is optional now.

plt.show()
```

And the result is this:

[image]